# Raise Exception on unwanted syscall

Tags: python, debugging, system-calls

I was told to fix a bug in a legacy application.

I can reproduce a bug, but I have no clue at which python source code line the error does get executed.

I can see the relevant failure with `strace`: A file gets opened, which should not get opened.

I would like to make the relevant open() linux-syscall raise an Exception in the python interpreter. My goal: I want to see the stacktrace to be able to fix the bug.

This way I could avoid the time consuming stepping through a lot of lines with a debugger.

The same with other words: if the syscall gets executed, which results in the strace output of `open("/somefile", O_RDONLY) = 4` the python interpreter should exit with an traceback.

Has anybody a solution?

Please leave a comment if you don't understand what I am looking for.

Comment: Would it be possible to temporarily rename `/somefile` so that whatever call attempts to open it fails? (Assuming the code doesn't already handle the missing file situation itself.)

Comment: No, it won't help to rename the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run python under gdb, set a (conditional) breakpoint on the `open()` syscall (or, rather, the stub function in libc through which it is called), and, when the breakpoint is hit, send a `SIGINT` signal to the python process and let it continue, whereupon the execution of the python script  should be interrupted with desired stack trace.

The shell script below automates that procedure.

Usage:

**`stack_trace_on_open`** *`filename`* **`-- python`** *`script.py`* `[`*`script args`*`]`

---

**stack_trace_on_open**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myname="$(basename "$0")"

if [[ $# -lt 4 || "$2" != '--' ]]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage: $myname <filename> -- python <script.py> [script args ...]"
    exit 1
fi

fname=$1
python_exe="$3"
shift 3

gdb -q "$python_exe" <<END
set breakpoint pending on
break open
condition 1 strcmp(\$rdi,"$fname") == 0
run "$@"
signal 2
cont
quit
END
```

---

Demonstration:

```
$ cat test.py 
import ctypes

clib = ctypes.CDLL(None)
fd = clib.open("/dev/urandom", 0)
clib.close(fd)

$ ./stack_trace_on_open /dev/urandom -- python test.py 
Reading symbols from python...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) (gdb) Function "open" not defined.
Breakpoint 1 (open) pending.
(gdb) (gdb) Starting program: /usr/bin/python "test.py"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, open64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) Continuing with signal SIGINT.

Breakpoint 1, open64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) Continuing.
Traceback (most recent call last):                #     <--------
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>             #     <--------
    fd = clib.open("/dev/urandom", 0)             #     <--------
KeyboardInterrupt
[Inferior 1 (process 14248) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Wow, works great. Up to now, I am not a gdb expert (yet). I think there are some magic things possible with it. You get the bounty.

Answer (score 5):

We can do a patch on `open` before import modules, here is an example:

in `test.py`:

```
def func():
    with open('test', 'w') as f:
        pass
```

in `test2.py`:

```
try:
    import __builtin__ # for python2
except ImportError:
    import builtins as __builtin__ #for python3

import copy
import traceback

orig_open = copy.copy(__builtin__.open)

def myopen(*args):
    traceback.print_stack()
    return orig_open(*args)

__builtin__.open = myopen

from test import func # Note that we import the module after patching on open()

func()
```

and when `func()` is called in `test2.py`, call stack will be printed:

```
$ python test2.py 
  File "test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    func()
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 4, in func
    with open('test', 'w') as f:
  File "test2.py", line 12, in myopen
    traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: I tried this, but this does not help. I guess the open sys-call  happens in a legacy c-extension.

Comment: @guettli if I were you, I would download the source code and use `grep -R` or `ag` to search the openned file's filename among all sources. Since  the open operation may happens in a binary library, if the library isn't complied with debug information, it would be hard to find the specific location where the `open()` is called even we can print the call stack.

Comment: since I had the idea "Stacktrace on syscall", I already found several use cases where this basic debugging tool would be helpful. Yes, for the use case of this question, I could find a work-around.

Comment: @guettli, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-e inject` of the `strace` command-line-tool.

`man strace`

```
-e inject=syscall_set

   Perform syscall tampering for the specified set of syscalls.  
   The syntax of the syscall_set specification
   is the same as in the -e trace option.

   At least one of error, retval, signal, delay_enter, 
   or delay_exit options has to be specified.  error and
   retval are mutually exclusive.

   If :error=errno option is specified, a fault is injected
   into a syscall invocation: the syscall number is
   replaced by -1 which corresponds to an invalid syscall
   (unless a syscall is specified with :syscall=  option), 
   and the error code is specified using a symbolic errno 
   value like ENOSYS or a numeric value within
   1..4095 range.
```